# CodeIgniter - Uma função para varios controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando o CI nos meus projetos, mas estou com uma duvida.
Tenho varios controllers que precisam acessar a mesma api, atualmente eu crio a conexão com uma função chamada "apicall" em todos os controllers, e dai uso ela com $this->apicall, oque preciso é otimizar isso, fazendo esta funcao apicall ( não só ela, mas varias outras que acontece a mesma coisa ) ser criada apenas uma vez, e poder usa-la em outros controllers. é possivel fazer isso no CI ?

Comment: Olá, por que você não usa Herança pra fazer isso?

Comment: @IpFranz acabei fazendo uma lib, funcionou melhor